# C# Writing to a csv file where a value has a string literal inside of it

Tags: c#, csv, parsing, string-literals

I am writing to a csv file and one of the values to be written to a row has a string literal in it as part of the value and I need it to remain in the value:

Example of the value: 
      "`<span><span style=\"font-family: arial,sans-serif;\"><\span><\span>`"

What is happening is the instead of keeping this under one column the comma forces it into the next column as the writer thinks this is what it is supposed to do.

My method:

```
    var value = "";
    var fileReadIn = new StreamReader(fileName);
    var headerFields = CsvRowToStringArray(fileReadIn.ReadLine());
    fileReadIn.Close();

    for (int i = 0; i < headerFields.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(headerFields[i]))
        {
            if (dict[headerFields[i]].Contains("\n"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("hell");
                Console.ReadKey();

                value += "\"" + dict[headerFields[i]].Replace("\n", @"\n").Replace(@"\", @"""\""" ).Replace(@"/", @"""/""")

                              +"\"" + ",";
            }
            else
            {
                value += @"""" + dict[headerFields[i]] + @"""" + ",";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            value += @"""" + "Null" + @"""" + ",";
        }
    }
        dict.Clear();
        return value;
```

As long as the string literal is not present it wraps the rows quotes and that fixes any comma issue, however I've tried using both methods below however am not having any luck

Comment: RFC-4180, paragraph "If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote."

Comment: @David I have tried double quotes, or so I thought, any examples?

Comment: Just clarifying -- what is required is DOUBLE-double quotes.  Is that what you tried?

Comment: @David like in the else statement near bottom with the Null?